# ConTeXt: backgroundcolor hides text after tikzpicture with makeup

Tags: tikz-pgf, context

I am trying to make slides with a tikz picture followed by some text. I am defining a makeup to get vertical centering. Through some trial and error, I found that setting the background color of the page seems to hide the text after the tikz picture and I have no clue what's going on.

Minimal example (Test2 does not show up for me):

```
%&context

% Loading tikz
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=color,backgroundcolor=white]

% Defining centered slides
\definemakeup[center]

\definestartstop
[CenterSlide]
[before={\page\startcentermakeup}, 
 after=\stopcentermakeup\page]

\starttext

\startCenterSlide

\starttikzpicture
\node[draw] (test) {Test1};
\stoptikzpicture \\

Test2 %<- I don't see this show up

\stopCenterSlide

\stoptext
```

I have 3 ways of making Test2 show up, none of which are really acceptable:

1. Remove `\setupbackgrounds` (but I would like to have a non-white background color)
2. Remove the makeup (which might suggest the nature of the problem, but I thought makeup was the right way to define slides)
3. Add any text before the `\startikzpicture` (again, might be indicative of something, but I want the option to have the diagram on the very top)

Could someone correct what I'm doing wrong or explain what's going on?

**Update:**

Based on the comment by @Ulrike Fischer, I can confirm that the issue seems to be with the color of the text. Forcing the text color makes Test2 show up:

```
\definecolor[myblack][c=0, m=.6, y=.3, k=100]
\color[myblack]{Test2} %<- This now shows up
```

Setting the color with `\startcolor` seems to also work in the minimal example, but not in my real document (suggesting that there are other interactions). Using a normally defined `black` also doesn't work.

Comment: After some more playing around, I realized that having headers/footers defined (but no background color) causes the same issue... I'll leave the question as is because that's the smallest example I can come up with.

Comment: I don't know much about context, but it looks like a bug to me. The color setup is confused by the starting tikzpicture. The text reappears if one defines a color myblack and use it for the following text. Ask on the context mailing list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Huh, I didn't even consider that it's printing in white... I can actually get Test2 to show up with the default black if I force the color. Thanks for the tip, I can use that to get things done while I try and figure out a less hacky solution.

Comment: Note that the problem disappears if you have some text before the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TikZ and ConTeXt have incompatible colour mechanisms.  Therefore you have to add

```
\dontleavehmode\forcecolorhack
```

in front of the TikZ picture to make it work.  You could also do it programmatically for every TikZ picture

```
\prependvalue{starttikzpicture}{\dontleavehmode\forcecolorhack}
```

I usually compile my TikZ pictures in an external document and then include them using `\externalfigure`.  This speeds up the build process of the main document and saves me from all the colour clashes.

Alternatively, just make your drawings with Metafun.  It's also much faster than TikZ.

```
%&context

% Loading tikz
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=color,backgroundcolor=white]

% Defining centered slides
\definemakeup[center]

\definestartstop
[CenterSlide]
[before={\page\startcentermakeup}, 
 after=\stopcentermakeup\page]

\starttext

\startCenterSlide

\dontleavehmode\forcecolorhack
\starttikzpicture
\node[draw] (test) {Test1};
\stoptikzpicture \\

Test2 %<- I don't see this show up

\stopCenterSlide

\stoptext
```

[image]

With Metafun you would use

```
\startMPinclusions
  input boxes ;
\stopMPinclusions
```

in the preamble and

```
\startMPcode
  boxit.test("Test 1") ;
  drawboxed(test) ;
\stopMPcode
```

in the document.