# Text color after a Tikz node at the beginning of a section in ConTeXt

Tags: tikz-pgf, context

I think I found a bug in the behaviour of tikz under ConTeXt. If an heading (a section, for example) is typeset in some color and it is followed by a tikz picture (either with a `\tikz` command or with `\starttikzpicture ... \stoptikzpicture`) which contains a node, the following text inherits the color of the heading. This does not happen if one of the following conditions occurs:

- the picture is not at the beginning of the section, that is there is some text before it, or
- the picture does not contain any node.

A MWE showing the (non-working) example and the correct cases is the following:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\usemodule[tikz]
\setuphead[section][color=red]

\starttext
\section[title=A section]
\tikz{\node[draw]{Inside a node};} If the section starts with a tikz
picture which contains a node, the following text inherits the color
of the previous heading.

\section[title=Another section]
If there is text before an node \tikz{\node[draw]{node text};}, the
text color is OK.

\section[title=A third section]
\tikz{\draw (0,0) --(1,0);} If there aren't nodes in the tikz picture,
the text color is OK.

\stoptext
```

Am I doing anything wrong? If not, is there any workaround?

Comment: `\prependvalue{tikz}{\dontleavehmode\forcecolorhack}`

Comment: Same issue as here: [ConTeXt: backgroundcolor hides text after tikzpicture with makeup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386679/context-backgroundcolor-hides-text-after-tikzpicture-with-makeup)

Comment: Thank you, that was quick! It solves the problem. I saw the linked post but it seemed a different issue so I didn't read until the end, sorry.

Comment: Nevermind :) You posted a good minimal example which enabled me to quickly identify the issue.  It's not expected that you know which questions are duplicates.  That is what the close button is for.